# Como rellenar un dataGridView desde otra clase? C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

quisiera saber como se podría rellenar un dataGridView desde otra clase que no fuera el propio form, he intentado instanciar el dataGridView en otra clase; pero no se rellena...

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el código que has probado y la "estructura" de clases para poder ayudarte con mas detalle.?

Answer (score 1):

La forma directa seria pasar por parametro a una funciona de esa clase la instancia del grid

```
public class Class1
{
   public void CargarGrid(DataGridView grid)
   {
      //accedes a los datos y usas
      grid.DataSource = dt;
   }
}
```

Pero aconsejaria que no tomes ese camino, sino que desde la clase envies los datos que uses para cargar los controles, de esta forma separas responsabilidades y la clase solo accede a los datos, dejando a la UI con la responsabilidad de acceder a sus controles. Eso se llama definir una capa de acceso a datos.

```
public class DataAccess
{
    public DataTable GetDatos()
    {
        //accedes a los datos y retornas la respuesta

        //dt seria el datatable, 
        //aunque si te animas a usar clases y List<> seria aun mejor
        return dt;  
    }
}
```

en la UI, que seria el form usas

```
public void Form1_Load(...)
{
   DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
   var dt = da.GetDatos();

   DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

esa seria la forma correcta

Comment: muchas gracias, me ha servido mucho tu respuesta!!

Comment: genial, me alegro que sea de utilidad

Answer (score -1):

Como dice el compa de arriba es mejor cargarlo a través del Load, si quieres llamar desde una Clase seria así:

NOMBREDELDATAGRIDVIEW.DataSource = NOMBREDELACLASE.NOMBREDELDATATABLE;

```
private void FrmPrincipal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DGV1.DataSource = ClasePrueba.DtOK;
}
```

Comment: Esto en que se diferencia de la otra respuesta, que hace exactamente lo mismo?

Comment: Si, tiene la misma función.